# MYSQL query won't return data using php

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if after all these hours of trying you could help me

After hours of trying i still have a problem retrieving data from a mysql query:
This is my query:

```
$res =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username =".$_SESSION['user']);
```

The user in the session is the current username.

i have an `if` statement like this:

```
if(!$res)
{
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

i run the code to check if the mysql_error isn't thrown but everytime i get this error:

> Invalid query: Unknown column 'Amando' in 'where clause'

Can someone explain to me what im doing wrong and maybe help me fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the `$_SESSION['user']` in quotes for MYSQL to consider it a string rather than a column name

```
$res =mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username ="'.$_SESSION['user'].'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the user variable. Try this

```
$res =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
```

You should also read up on [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and maybe [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) since your code is vulnerable for SQL injections as it is now. Or at least it can be, depending on if you have secured/validated the session variable before you use it in the query.